# Cannot delete files from C:\

Tags: vb.net

What's Wrong With this code?
i wrote this program to delete some files without sending it to recycle bin
every time i run the program and try to delete file in (C) Root
an error shown in code menu told me that file cannot be deleted

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub BtnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnDelete.Click
    Try
        Dim x As String
        x = txtfolder.Text
        If txtfolder.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Write An Address Then Click ^Goto^", _
            "Super Deleter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
            MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        ElseIf MessageBox.Show("Are you sure You want to Delete File(s)?", _
                "Super Deleter", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                MessageBoxIcon.Warning) _
                = DialogResult.Yes Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(lstbox.SelectedItem)
            MessageBox.Show("File Has been Deleted Successfuly!", _
            "Siper Deleter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
            lstbox.Items.Clear()
            For Each folder As String In _
            My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(x)
                lstbox.Items.Add(folder)
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Can't Delete This File", "Error", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub gotobtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles gotobtn.Click
    Try
        Dim x As String
        x = txtfolder.Text
        lstbox.Items.Clear()
        For Each folder As String In _
        My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(x)
            lstbox.Items.Add(folder)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Write An Address Then Click ^Goto^", _
        "Super Deleter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: an app needs elevated rights to act in certain directories, the windows root folder (typically 'C:\') is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) replace `lstbox.SelectedItem` by  `lstbox.SelectedItem.tostring`

2)You have to check if the file already exists use `if system.io.file.exists(lstbox.SelectedItem.toString) then : DO SOMETHING : end if`

3)use `System.IO.File.Delete ("YOUR FILE")` instead of `My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile`

and sorry for the bad langage =p

Comment: Thx bro... Sorry for not answering all that time.